# is there any object to object Mapper for node.js?

Tags: node.js, orm, model, sequelize.js, mapper

I was hoping if there is any way to dynamically map my API's response to my model class in node js. for example I have a model dynamically defined using sequelize-Auto which looks like this

```
return sequelize.define('clients', {
id: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true
},
dateCreated: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  allowNull: true
},
dateModified: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  allowNull: true
},
createdBy: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
  allowNull: true
},
createdByName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
  allowNull: true
},
modifiedBy: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
  allowNull: true
},
modifiedByName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
  allowNull: true
},
c_code: {
  type: Sequelize.TEXT,
  allowNull: true
},
c_name: {
  type: Sequelize.TEXT,
  allowNull: true
},
...
...
...
}
```

and this is how I am mapping the response from my API but if I change the model(which happens dynamically) I have to manually update the fields in my controller as shown the code below

```
 const client = {
    id: req.body.id,
    dateCreated: req.body.dateCreated,
    dateModified: req.body.dateModified,
    createdBy: req.body.createdBy,
    createdByName: req.body.createdByName,
    modifiedBy: req.body.modifiedBy,
    modifiedByName: req.body.modifiedByName,
    c_code: req.body.c_code,
    ...
    ...
    ...

  }; 
models.clients
    .upsert(client);
```

I was hoping if there was a way where I can extract my model object from `res.body` dynamically something like `automapper` from .net

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AutoMapper](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/strategies/sequelize). It has first-class support for Sequelize to automatically map to your models.

Alternatively, if you don't want to define a DTO but just take the req.body and map it to your model, you could use [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) with the `excludeExtraneousValues` option to discard any extra props.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create new modal entity class where you can pass the body object and inside it's constructor use `Object.assign` as below code snippet.

```js
class ClientEntity {
    id;
    dateCreated;
    dateModified;
    createdBy;

    constructor(data) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

//assuming below request object
let req = {
    body: {
        id: 1,
        dateCreated: new Date(),
        dateModified: new Date(),
        createdBy: 'John',
    }
}
let client = new ClientEntity(req.body)

console.log(client);
```

Comment: won't I still be updating my code in case of my table has changed? I wanted to automate that part.